# List of Figures, List of tables in toc

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using the `book` class, and I can't display the `List of Figures` and the `List of Tables` in the table of contents.

Is it automatic, or should I force them with `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}` ?

If I have to force them, is it possible to use the generic name ? It could prevent me from having one title in the toc, and another on the page of the lof (if I change in one line an note the other).

What I'm thinking is something like :
`\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}`, where `\listfigurename` is like `\chaptername`, and is the name of the variable LaTeX uses...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the `book` document class, I would insert the instruction

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

in the preamble. That way, pointers to the List of Figures and the List of Tables will be inserted in the Table of Contents, while omitting a pointer to the ToC itself.